# Rails and Devise manually sending confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey I am manually sending confirmation email as such
`user.skip_confirmation!`

`Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(user, user.confirmation_token)`
with custom generated confirmation token

````
def generate_confirmation_token!
  user.confirmation_token = Array.new(6) { rand(10) }.join
  user.confirmation_sent_at = DateTime.current
  user.save!
end```

Is it safe to do that way?
I am using custom generate_confirmation_token! because I only want 6 digit for OTP
````

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance of a match with another user, I would use:

```
user.confirmation_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest user.email || Time.current
```

Comment: I only want 6 digit token. Is there a way I achieve it with your code?

Comment: yes, you can just add `[0..5]`. but then there is no need to use that solution, in which case you can use this:

   `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(4)`

I would add a check that there is only one such valid token at one time.